# Ubuntu update to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates

I wanted to update my Ubuntu 13.04 OS to 14.04 Os. I downloaded the 32-bit (.ISO) file for the 14.04. Since, i run both Ubuntu and windows on my laptop, i was wondering if i can just update Ubuntu without losing all my current win and Ubuntu files. Is it possible? or do i need to install it fresh? 
if, in fact, update is possible, can anyone tell me how to do it? Also, i have tried to mount the .ISO file using various software, but my software center has gone nuts; it doesn't let me install any software.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes it is definitely possible

You can also do it from installation cd/bootable usb it won't bother your windows installation. You'll just update from 13.04 to 14.04.There will come an option while installation.

**Prerequisites**

- Just run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` from terminal

### Now

1. Run the update-manager application from the Unity Dash or a command line.
2. In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.
3. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.
4. Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
5. Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
6. In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.
7. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
8. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
9. Click Upgrade.
10. Follow the on-screen instructions.